# Validation on form action when using preventDefault

Tags: php, asp.net, ajax, jquery

I'm making a ajax call to a server side function to send an email. It works fine. My issue is before sending the email i need to validate the captcha where the server side code resides in CaptchaValidation.php. If i call "CaptchaValidation.php" on form action it should work fine but here since i'm doing a ajax call i need to use e.preventDefault();. So that form action is not working.

How can i make it work?

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>
 <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#divLoading').hide();
            $('#appointment').submit(function (e) {
                e.preventDefault();



                var serviceURL = 'WebService.asmx/SendMail';
                var Name = $("#fname").val();
                var Email = $("#email").val();
                var Telephone = $("#phone").val();
                var Comment = $("#comment").val();

                if ($("#fname").val().length == 0) {
                    alert("Please Enter Name");
                    $("#fname").focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if ($("#email").val().length == 0) {
                    alert("Please Enter Your Email Address.");
                    $("#email").focus();
                    return false;
                }

                if (Email.indexOf("@") == -1) {
                    alert("Please Enter Your Email Address.");
                    $("#email").focus();
                    return false;
                }
                if (Email.indexOf(".") == -1) {
                    alert("Please Enter Your Email Address.");
                    $("#email").focus();
                    return false;
                }

                $('#divLoading').show();

                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: serviceURL,
                    data: '{"name":"' + Name + '","address":"' + Email + '","telephone":"' + Telephone + '","comment":"' + Comment + '"}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: successFunc,
                    error: errorFunc
                });

                function successFunc(data, status) {

                    //  alert("Mail Sent!");
                    $('#divLoading').hide();
                    window.location = "contat-submit.php";

                }

                function errorFunc() {
                    // alert('error');
                }

            });

        });

</script>
</head>
<body>
   <form name="appointment" id="appointment" method="post" action="CaptchaValidation.php">
    <div>
    </div><div id="leftcolumn4"><div class="h2">Contact Form</div>
      <form name="appointment" id="Form1" method="post" action="send_contact.php">
Full Name:
<br />
<label>
  <input name="fname" type="text" class="form-input" id="fname" size="30" />
</label> 
<br /><br />

Email Address:<br />
<label>
  <input name="email" type="text" class="form-input" id="email" size="30" />
</label><br /><br />
Telephone:
<br />
<label>
  <input name="phone" type="text" class="form-input" id="phone" size="30" />
</label> 
<br /><br />
Your Comment:<br />
<label>
<textarea name="comment" cols="28" rows="4" class="form-input-box" id="comment"></textarea><br />

      <br />
&nbsp;</label><input name="submit" type="submit" class="form-input-submit" value="Submit" id="btnMail"/>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you dont use `$.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: 'CaptchaValidation.php',
                    data:... `

Comment: How this is related to `asp.net`?

Comment: Direct the post to the captcha validation first, then upon successful validation call the form submit function, else display error message.\

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. Change the Submit button to a simple button so that on click of that button the form will not submit.
2. On Click of that button call a function which will have call e.preventDefault();

   function callSubmit() {
      // do ajax call
   }
3. You are doing ajax call in e.preventDefault() function. So in AJAX response, you have to check if the AJAX response is correct then do a form submit using:

   $('#appointment').submit()
4. Now just remove the e.preventDefault(); function from you form.submit function you have written. This will allow to AJAX submit and send email.